# Join multiple tables and show the current table

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to achieve maybe hard to explain so I will try my best.

I would like to join the results of three tables in mysql and in the results include the table name/or alias so i know which table the information has come from.

All my tables have common columns.

Comment: with no code? It's hard to help u.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
select 'mytable1', column1, column2
union
select 'mytable2', column1, column2
union
select 'mytable3', column1, column2
```

Comment: what if i have extra columns which do not appear in each table

Comment: you want them to be shown in "joined" table? if you know their names you can put '' in select clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias feature of mysql

like this

```
select table1.col1 as table1_col1, table2.col1 as table2_col1...
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean something like this?

```
SELECT t1.*, "t1" as tablename FROM t1
UNION 
SELECT t2.*, "t2" as tablename FROM t2
```

where `t1` and `t2` is your tables

By the way: it is not very correct to store data in such way. If you have necessity to union data from both tables in a single query, you should think of merging your tables in one with adding more valueable attribute as a new column (and probably add it to the key). For example, your tables are

```
CREATE TABLE american_cars(id INT, company TEXT, model TEXT)
CREATE TABLE european_cars(id INT, company TEXT, model TEXT)
```

then you should merge it as

```
CREATE TABLE cars(id INT, company TEXT, model TEXT, region TEXT)
```

or something like that.

Comment: I will try combining the tables but in the long run the dataset may get to large for a single table with indexes